# Create progress bar with CSS (concave shape)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, radial-gradients

I trying to create create a progress bar with css like this

[image]

With the code below I found this result
[image]

But I want the inverse, can someone please help me?

```css
.first-bar {
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(20px 20px at calc(100% + 4px) 50%, #8e7cc3 18px, #8e7cc3 19px, #8e7cc3 20px, #4a86e8 21px);
}

.second-bar {
  background: radial-gradient(20px 20px at calc(100% + 4px) 50%, #ffab40 18px, #ffab40 19px, #ffab40 20px, #8e7cc3 21px);
}

.third-bar {
  background: radial-gradient(20px 20px at calc(100% + 4px) 50%, #6aa84f 18px, #6aa84f 19px, #6aa84f 20px, #ffab40 21px);
}

.fourth-bar {
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  background: radial-gradient(20px 20px at calc(100% + 4px) 50%, #6aa84f 18px, #6aa84f 19px, #6aa84f 20px, #6aa84f 21px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row col-10 text-white text-bold text-center">
  <div class="first-bar py-1" :style="{'width':'25%'}">25</div>
  <div class="second-bar py-1" :style="{'width':'25%'}">25</div>
  <div class="third-bar py-1" :style="{'width':'25%'}">25</div>
  <div class="fourth-bar py-1" :style="{'width':'25%'}">25</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the full CSS code?

Comment: yes i'm sure, i think the 'run code snippet' doesn't  work because there's 'row' class of bootstrap which is not declared here

Comment: Can you add the bootstrap link which you are using?

Comment: @Gharbi if thats bootstrap your class combination of `row col-10` is wrong. Cols are supposed to be _immediate **childs**_ of rows, not be the same element. Also i added the bootstrap stylesheet to your snippet so the styles actually work

Comment: You could try using the z-index attribute to make sure that the fourth bar is displayed on top of the third bar. That way, for each bar, the left border of every element is visible, while the border on the right is covered by the element on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid a lot of z-index using a 3D transform trick and it will work for any number of elements:

```css
.bar-progress {
  margin:10px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; /* here */
}

.bar-progress div {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform:rotateY(-0.1deg); /* and here */
}

.bar-progress div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -45px
}

.first-bar  {background: #4a86e8;}
.second-bar {background: #8e7cc3;}
.third-bar  {background: #ffab40;}
.fourth-bar {background: #6aa84f}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bar-progress">
  <div class="first-bar">25</div>
  <div class="second-bar">25</div>
  <div class="third-bar">25</div>
  <div class="fourth-bar">25</div>
</div>

<div class="bar-progress">
  <div class="first-bar">25</div>
  <div class="second-bar">25</div>
  <div class="third-bar">25</div>
  <div class="fourth-bar">25</div>
  <div class="third-bar">25</div>
  <div class="second-bar">25</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add a `z-index` on each element to define on which level element should be displayed

```css
.bar-progress {
  width:60%;
}

.bar-progress div {
 text-align:center;
 padding-left:8px;
 padding-right:8px;
 border-radius:20px;
 color:white;
 width:25%;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
}

.bar-progress div:first-child {
  margin-left:0 !important;
}

.bar-progress div {
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.first-bar {
  background: #4a86e8;
  z-index:4;
}

.second-bar {
  background: #8e7cc3;
  z-index:3;
}

.third-bar {
  background: #ffab40;
  z-index:2;
}

.fourth-bar {
  background: #6aa84f;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bar-progress">
  <div class="first-bar">25</div>
  <div class="second-bar">25</div>
  <div class="third-bar">25</div>
  <div class="fourth-bar">25</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to give the original result rather than the desired result.

Comment: yes i invert the z-index to have the wanted result